# @abstract not displaying in view for response-to-response doc

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm putting together a course question/answer app.

The course is the parent doc, question is a response, and the answer is a response-to-response.

I created a hierarchical view and want to take a few chars of the question and answer to display.

I created a computed field on the question and answer forms that do an @abstract of the RichText field where people will be typing the question and answer.

After struggling with this for a while, the @abstract for the question finally showed up in the view but I can't get anything from the question doc to show up.  I see a blank line in the view and can open it but nothing from that doc will show up.

I tried running through the fixup, compact, and updall on the database but nothing changed.  Tried rebuilding the indexes but nothing happened.  I then tried to recreate it in a test database and also got odd behavior.

Any thoughts on what I might be able to do to tease something from the answer doc?  An Abstract from the RichText answer field is what I really need.

Thanks!
Clem

Comment: Show us the code that you use to get the abstract from the main document...

Comment: It's just the @abstract call: @Abstract( [TextOnly] ;  40  ;  "Q: "  ;  "Question"  )

Comment: Hi Clem! Just a sanity check... Am I understanding you to say you can't get anything to show up for the answer doc? Not just the computed field with the @Abstract, but no other fields as well?

Comment: Silly question: Is the field name correct in the answer's column formula?